# When is the 'handleEmptyBody‘ method in the interface ‘RequestBodyAdvice’ called？

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

handleEmptyBody

```java
    @Override
    public Object handleEmptyBody(Object body, HttpInputMessage inputMessage, MethodParameter parameter,
            Type targetType, Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> converterType) {
        log.debug("handleEmptyBody");
        return body;
    }
```

---

```java
    @PostMapping ("test")
    public void test(@RequestBody String json){

    }
```

1. If use a String argument, the handleEmptyBody can be called when the body is empty

```java
    @PostMapping ("test")
    public void test(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> json){

    }
```

2. If use a Map argument, there will be errors, and the handleEmptyBody can't be called when the body is empty

   > WARN (AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:199) [logException] Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Required request body is missing: public void test(java.util.Map)]

Whether the spring framework has tried some type conversion before?

Answer (score 0):

If you expect the user to not need to provide a body value (and you want to handle empty bodies via the Request Advice you specified, you need to denote that the `@RequestBody` is not required.

`@RequestBody(required=false)`.

This should allow you to get past the exception you are facing and also allow your `RequestBodyAdvice` to fire.

Additionally, I am assuming that it worked for a `String` because in those circumstances, Spring injects an empty string, and so the request body isn't missing.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer. My requirement is to inject the contents of the header into the body. I tried `@requestbody (required=false)`, but the whole RequestBodyAdvice is skipped when the body is empty.So what I'm going to do is I'm going to use `@request Body String json` and I'm going to do my own json parsing.

Comment: By the way, I tried to add a Filter on the outside of the most, here to empty body processing is feasible.